# Change the SharedPreferences of another application using super user

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, su

I'm trying to use super user to modify another application's SharedPreferences.

Here is how I do :

```
        Process suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());

        os.writeBytes("echo \"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?><map><string name='commentAuthorName'>toto</string></map>\" > /data/data/com.adobe.reader/shared_prefs/com.adobe.reader.preferences.xml' \n");

        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();
        os.close();

        suProcess.waitFor();
```

But what happens is that my application freezes.

What did I do wrong ?

Also, would there be a better way to modify the SharedPreferences of another application I do not own ?

Thanks in advance.

Zab

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the single quote at the end of the line after preferences.xml.

Comment: I just did but it still freezes on: Process suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");   Any idea why ? I'm running on a rooted version of Android 3.1, other rooted apps work fine on this device and my super user version is: V2.3.6.1

Comment: It's probably waiting for you to type your password.  There are secure ways to do this, and calling su via a shell call is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I know now why my application was freezing (just to precise, it was freezing on: Process suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");).

The application I'm developping is a native extension to AIR for Android. I was launching my application from Flash builder and apparently, this causes the freeze...

When launching normally the application from the device, everything works fine.